# What would be the opposite of delighted?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

On a scale/axis that represents emotional response with regard to satisfaction, what would be the opposite of "delighted"?

- delighted
- satisfied
- neutral
- dissatisfied
- ???

If it helps, a [paper on measuring satisfaction in banking](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/34724/1/MPRA_paper_34724.pdf) says this about "delight":

> Traditionally, delight has been thought of a blend of joy and surprise (Kumar, Olshavsky, & King, 2001). However, a recent study suggested that customer can be delighted without being surprised (Kumar et al., 2001). Although joy remains an important element of delight, the study explained that a greater number of people are exhilarated, thrilled and to a lesser extent exuberant (Kumar et al).
>
> Satisfied customers are purely at ease. Delighted customers on the other hand have greater admiration for the firm and its services. Paul (2000, p. 34) stated ‘Unfortunately, people don’t talk about adequate service. Instead, they tell anyone who will listen about really bad or really delightful services’.

There are of course many antonyms in the dictionary to choose from – what I'm after is the most appropriate/apt choice given the context.

I am of course looking for a single word and not a phrase as I'll be using it as a marker on the axis/scale (and all the other points are single-words).

There's a survey instrument that collects data which can then be plotted on a graph, with one axis of "a scale/axis that represents emotional response with regard to satisfaction". So, the broader context is in commerce/marketing/product-design (vs. say literature).

Comment: You mentioned `most appropriate/apt choice given the context`. But where did you actually mention the context?

Comment: @alwayslearning There's a survey instrument that collects data which can then be plotted on a graph, with one axis of "a scale/axis that represents emotional response with regard to satisfaction". So, the broader context is in commerce/marketing/product-design (vs. say literature).

Comment: Hi @Erics, *delighted* has [many antonyms](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/delighted/antonyms). Can you please note in your question which you've considered but rejected, and why you rejected them?

Comment: If delighted is a mix of "joy and surprise", so I guess the antonym would be a mix of sadness toward something expected then "gloom" but it would not fit here.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done; questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: One is tempted to suggest _lighted_ (or should that be _lit_?) …

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's clever. Perhaps even relight.

Answer (score 1):

> **Dismay**
>   [dis-mey]
>   /verb (used with object)
>
> 2. to surprise in such a manner as to disillusion.
> 3. to alarm; perturb.
>
> /noun
>
> 5. sudden disillusionment.
> 6. agitation of mind; perturbation; alarm.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dismay)